# How do VBOs/FBOs/DisplayLists work in Haskell's OpenGl bindings?

Tags: haskell, monads, fbo, vbo, displaylist

Haskell is about computation by calculation of values.

DisplayLists / FBOs / VBOs are very very *stateful* by nature. I.e. "give me a display list / buffer object".

How do these bindings work in Haskell?

[I do understand monads; so a technical explaination, as opposed to a fluffy one, is preferred].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HOpenGL](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGL) does everything in the IO monad.  The API it presents is more OpenGL-like than Haskell-like.  For example,

```
do
    -- create a new display list
    dl <- defineNewList $ do
        -- put some
        -- drawing code
        -- in here

    -- call a pre-defined display list
    callList dl
```

So all the low-level OpenGL interactions *do* end up being very stateful.

Comment: How do you release lists then? Or does it get auto-freed when the varaible falls out of scope?

Comment: You have to manually free it with `deleteLists`, or reuse the ID for another display list with `defineList`.

Comment: darn it; i was really hoping for something mind blowingly elegant